# Problems with large torrents in uTorrent Server @ Ubuntu Server and NTFS partition

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs, utorrent

I'm using uTorrent Server build 27079 with Ubuntu 10.10 Server. When I'm trying to download large file (>20 Gb) to NTFS volume, ntfs-3g driver starts throttling (top shows mount.ntfs-3g taking 100% CPU), torrent downloading speed drastically decreases to 10-100 Kbps, and respective partition becomes unresponsive for read/write operations. Turned file pre-allocation off and diskio.sparse_files on, no help so far.

This is definitely big file downloading by utserver problem, because smaller torrents are loading as expected - with up to 3 Mbps speed, and stopping utserver service removes cpu load/fs lags.
**edit**
People on uTorrent forums says this is related to ntfs-3g. No solutions how to fix though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jpa](http://tuxera.com/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=1052) from Tuxera support (ntfs-3g developers) suggested defragmenting disk or backup/recreate files sequentially : [link](http://tuxera.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30393).